# Does a jQuery or JavaScript module exist that creates a SQL query builder interface?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

We are currently using something called QueryBuilderWidget that is based on script.aculo.us. This was implemented a while back, and I can't find the project's site anymore.  But, it looks very similar to [YUI's Query Builder](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/querybuilder).

The functionality is fine, but we don't use scriptaculous for anything else.  The rest of the site uses jQuery or straight JavaScript. I'm looking for a module with similar features that is either straight JavaScript or jQuery. I have seen [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SQL_QUERY_BUILDER), and I could use that as a starting point, if there isn't anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for a web-based ad-hoc 'pivot table' style UI, and stumbled on http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/index.html which seems to do a nice job with the filter/where clause piece.

Answer (score 3):

I recently released a JavaScript SQL query builder which works in the browser and with node.js - http://squeljs.org

Comment: That's interesting, but I'm more interested in the UI portion.  I'm looking for something that makes it easy for an end user to filter data.

Comment: @Raynos only the source is in CoffeeScript. The main library is actually pre-compiled and minified Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly too late but I'm working on a JavaScript SQL Builder UI that will do joins etc http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/ that might be of interest. At an early stage but I'm very interested in what features people think are missing/broken.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  Any thoughts on allowing ORs instead of just ANDs?

Comment: Definitely. It is going to be part of the next milestone. I've got to have a proper think about how to make it clear to the user in what order the expression is going to be evaluated. My current preference is for "pretty printing" but I'm worried that is just clear to geeks so I need to test it out on non-technical users.

Comment: I've put a first stab at and/or up. My email address is on there now if you want more detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

From here you could find your answer

https://github.com/gantir/jsexpbuilder

You can also customize it as per your requirement